# RecyclerView.ItemDecoration divider after the last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to add divider after the last item in the list for RecyclerView?

Comment: your row item should have bottom line added. Try puttin View at the bottom in xml file of the item

Comment: I use this way for now. But how to achieve this with ItemDecoration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a element (maybe an empty instance of your model) to your itemList inside your RecyclerView adapter. Then override the `getItemViewType` inside your adapter.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType;
    Model item = getItem(position);
    if (item.getId == -1) {
        viewType = R.layout.item_divider;
    } else  {
        viewType = R.layout.item_model;
    }
    return viewType;
}
```

Then on your `onCreateViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                       int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(viewType, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v, viewType);
}
```

Finally on your ViewHolder inflate the views depending on the viewType:

```
MyViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
        super(itemView);
        if (viewType == R.layout.item_model) {
            //inflate model view
        } else if (viewType == R.layout.item_divider) {
           //inflate divider view
        }
    }
```

And the same when you bind the data:

```
void bind(Model model) {
        if (model.getId != -1) {
            //bind your model data
        } else {
           //bind if you need divider data.
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a workaround of this problem. Maybe there are some standard way? 
But it will work. Thanks!

Comment: This is a simple way to make the divider scroll with recycler, otherwise, you need to add a ScrollView and put inside a layout with the recycler and the divider below. But is better this way, because you inflate less views.